Looking for a "Space Nazi" movie from mid 2000s
I remember seeing a movie about 8 or so years ago. It was a rather interesting science fiction movie that was very well directed for being as old as it was. I don't remember the plot, only a short scene dealing with "space Nazis" on a ship. The movie seems to be linked to the conspiracy theory about missing Third Reich Nazi party members hiding on the moon.
Nazi soldiers were made to fight each other to the death while climbing on hanging chains, for reasons unremembered. One of the few survivors was an Asian guy with his eye hanging out of its socket. All the dead soldiers were literally thrown in the trash, along with one survivor who was pretending to be dead, and dumped on a planet used specifically as a garbage dump.
This is all I can remember of the movie but I know I watched more and was very interested in it and would like to see it again but I cannot remember the name of it. If anyone could help me I would appreciate it greatly.

Was the film in English? And was it 8 years old? (If not, how old was it approximately?)

I believe you are looking for the 1998 Paul WS Anderson directed film Soldier starring Kurt Russell.
While there are no Nazis there is a lot of similar costuming and attitude.  Kurt Russell is one of a group of orphans that is taken and raised by the government to be an emotionless soldier who doesn't question orders.  The fight scene you describe takes place between Russell's character and Jason Scott Lee who plays a new breed of genetically engineered soldier.
Here's the trailer which contains part of that scene:




Thank you. That's what I was looking g for. I saw it when I was in foster care and didn't think much of it but I remembered seeing it and wanted to watch it again though the fight scene was all I could remember. I thought for some reason it was another movie linked to the conspiracy theory about missing Third Reich Nazi party members hiding on the moon, but I would guess not. My memory is terrible. But thank you, this has been buggi g me for a while.

@Steven If this is answer is the correct solution to your problem, feel free to accept it.

While it was not tied to Nazis, it did share ties with Blade Runner with the story being that initially, it was supposed to be set in the same universe. There's a reference to fighting at Tannhauser Gate in his profile.

You probably confused the movie from the other answer with:
Iron Sky (2012)
It's all about Nazis on the moon.
But it was only 3 yrs before you asked the question.





This doesn't seem to fit his plot at all, though, other than for the word "Nazi" which he probably used rather colloquially in his question.

Exactly WHAT PART of  "missing Third Reich Nazi party members hiding on the moon" in his description did you NOT read before down-voting me and removing links to IMDB from my post? THIS movie JUST HAPPENS to be about "missing Third Reich Nazi party members hiding on the moon". Please be so kind as to explain that part of MY MISTAKE.

You might want to calm down a little. I did not remove any links at all, I merely cleaned up some formatting. Besides that I can't find what description you are referring to, there is nothing of the sort in his question. Neither is my comment "argumentative" or "spiteful". All I did was pointing out that I didn't see this answer fitting to the question and explaining the reason for my downvote. There was neither any sort of spite or the like. Please refrain from taking any form of criticism and downvotes personal.

Not to mention the fact that the question is titled "Looking for a “Space Nazi” movie from mid 2000s"

I had:
Iron Sky (2012)
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1034314/
You deleted both, then added the Title and year back. the IMDB link no longer appears on my screen. I included it so he could find more info on the movie to determine if this was what he was looking for, and had gotten the two movies in question confused.

I don't know what you're talking about deleting anything. All I did was adjust the formatting to use the title as the link. I haven't deleting anything of the sort, the link is still very much there. However, I have noticed that comment you seem to be referring to now, I'll try to add it into the question so it becomes a bit more apparent why this answer makes sense.

I would, however, advise you to not try to desperately see malice and spite around every corner. It helps a great deal to not lose your sanity over honest criticism of your stuff.
